# Frictional force on smooth surface

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

While walking on ice , one should take small steps to avoid slipping. This is because smaller steps ensure

$A)$ smaller friction

$B)$ larger friction

$C)$ larger Normal force

$D)$ smaller Normal force

I thought the answer to be option $B)$ because our weight is not spread out much on the surface if we take small steps. Thus a larger friction. However the book gives the correct answer as $A)$ . Please help me and point out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Not me, but you should look at [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)

Comment: I think a diagram which explains why this happens and which justifies the answer(not necessarily the book answer) will be more helpful rather than quoting other answers,  I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the friction force of the ice that propels you forward. That force equals is equal and opposite to the force you apply backwards on the surface by your foot. The larger the steps you take the greater the backward force you apply that has to be resisted by a greater ice friction force. When your backward force gets too large it exceeds the maximum possible static friction force of the ice, and slippage occurs.

The smaller your steps the less backward force you apply and the less friction force the ice needs to apply to you to prevent slippage. So the answer is A.

I have added the figure below (which I used for a different question) which might further help. The larger the steps, the smaller the angle theta and the greater the friction force needed on the ice to propel the runner.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See,smaller steps genuinely mean that the contact area of our feet with earth reduces.
From Feynman 's 2nd lecture.,we know that when two surfaces come in contact they exert electromagnetic force which results in a normal reaction perpendicular to the tangential surface.
So lesser the surface area lesser is the normal reaction force.In classical mechanics frictional force in magnitude is directly proportional to the normal reaction .Hence frictional force reduces.
In other way frictional force is the vector product of sheer stress and surface area.
So both the relations explain the smaller frictional option.

Comment: I have deleted a comment discussion which contained inappropriate comments from more than one user. [Some guidance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/conduct).